# What is the difference between standard utc and dates with an appended '+00:00'

Tags: date, format, utc, difference

Is there any significant difference between these two formats??
I am trying to keep a consistent format throughout my table so I can compare the dates later on.

first fomrat
2014-02-05 00:00:00+00:00

second format
2014-02-05 00:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just indicates the [timezone offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets). `+00:00` is used to indicate no offset.

To save a date from Australia you might save the date as `2014-02-05 00:00:00+06:30`

Comment: Correct answer. The first date-time in question says the moment is in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The second date-time is ambiguous because without an offset we don't know if that represents midnight in Hong Kong or Montréal or Paris. Also, those date-times are in standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. That is a very sensible and useful standard to study.